# Can I create more than one repository for GitHub Pages?

Tags: github, repository, github-pages

I  created a repository for hosting a blog on GitHub.

Is there any way that I can create additional repositories to host multiple blogs, or am I limited to just one since *username.github.io* can only be used once?

Answer (score 240, accepted):

You can have one site published to `https://<username>.github.io` by publishing to the master branch of a repository named “username.github.io” (substituting your actual username).

You can also have an additional site per GitHub project published to `https://<username>.github.io/<project>`. Project settings let you [choose which branch and directory to publish](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site).

A better description is available in the [GitHub Pages documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages), including options for using custom domain names.

([since April 2013](https://github.com/blog/1452-new-github-pages-domain-github-io), all `username.github.com` are now `username.github.io`)

Comment: It is now possible to have a page on the Master branch of any repository.

Comment: Stephen, what do you mean by `gh-pages` branch. I have pushed my website to master branch of such project repository as shared above in the answer however I get the error `There isn't a GitHub Pages site here.`

Comment: @KrishnaOza By default you push GitHub Pages sites to a branch named “gh-pages” instead of “master“, but there is a repository setting to publish the master branch instead. See the [documentation for choosing a publishing source](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site#choosing-a-publishing-source) for exact instructions.

Comment: "Project sites will publish whatever you push to the "gh-pages" branch by default." However, gh-pages is not automatically published as a page. You may need to go to Settings > Pages and ensure Source has both a branch and folder selected otherwise you'll get a 404.

Comment: is there a limit to how many websites can you host? for example: the limit is 3, if you want to host your fourth website, you have to take down one of your first three.

Answer (score 35):

No you are not limited, it is possible to have multiple GitHub Pages sites within one account. Create another GitHub repository and push your site files to the gh-pages branch. This would result in the site being hosted at tshepang.github.io/repo-name

Now, push another file "CNAME" to the same repository and branch and fill it with movies.tshepang.net. Log in to your DNS host and add the CNAME to point to "tshepang.github.io" (just like the original site).

This would allow you to have seemingly two different sites on different domains. This would not work for having two or more sub-domains within github.io itself.

Comment: I see only one branch i.e. master and no branch named `gh-pages` is created.

Comment: @KrishnaOza you have to create the gh-pages branch yourself for it to work

Answer (score 22):

There is a possibility to host multiple pages within the same repository having **sub-pages** if you are fine with code duplication.

The latest version of my website is hosted on http://username.github.io/REPONAME
This is a screenshot of the structure of my root repository where I host the latest version of my website:

[image: Repository root folder]

**Inside folder "2.4.0" I can host a previous version of the same page** ,which is then reachable at: http://username.github.io/REPONAME/2.4.0
This is the structure of the folder 2.4.0:
[image: Repository folder 2.4.0]

Using this methodology of sub-pages within a main page, you can host multiple sub-pages within one main page.

Answer (score 6):

**You can only create `one` user or organization site for each GitHub account. Project sites, whether owned by an organization or a user account, are `unlimited`.**

## GitHub Pages sites

There are three types of GitHub Pages sites:
 `project`, `user`, and `organization`. Project sites are connected to a specific project hosted on GitHub, such as a JavaScript library or a recipe collection. User and organization sites are connected to a specific GitHub account.

To publish a user site, you must create a repository owned by your user account that's named `<user>.github.io`. To publish an organization site, you must create a repository owned by an organization that's named `<organization>.github.io`. Unless you're using a custom domain, user and organization sites are available at `http(s)://<username>.github.io` or `http(s)://<organization>.github.io.`

The source files for a project site are stored in the same repository as their project. Unless you're using a custom domain, project sites are available at `http(s)://<user>.github.io/<repository>` or `http(s)://<organization>.github.io/<repository>`.

The publishing source for your GitHub Pages site is the branch and folder where the source files for your site are stored. If the default publishing source exists in your repository, GitHub Pages will automatically publish a site from that source. The default publishing source for user and organization sites is the root of the default branch for the repository. The default publishing source for project sites is the root of the `gh-pages` branch.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround if you don't want to make separate repositories for your different sites but just want to host them. In your io repo, create an index.html file on your master branch that acts as a table of contents linking to your other sites(subDirectories) index.html files. The username.github.io master branch seems to be the landing page that enables the hosting, so if it doesn't see an index file linking out to your separate projects, it won't register your subdirectories. After this all you need is the URL to whatever project you want to view. The io basically behaves like a giant single website with all your separate projects on it. Of course, if you would rather have separate repositories, gh-pages is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can create multiple blogs in your github account.

1. One repository can be created under your username. Push your code to branch `gh-pages` and you can see the site on `<username>.github.io`
2. Another one can be created under your organisation. For this you will have to create your organization first. Create a new repository under this organisation and push your code to `gh-pages`. You can see your site on `<organization-name>.github.io`
3. You can also create for each of your project and the site will be available on `<username>.github.io/<repository>`

Please refer [this](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/working-with-github-pages/about-github-pages) for more information on github pages.

Answer (score 0):

Today I created another site and rather than creating branch gh-pages I have configured the master branch in a repository setting --> GitHub pages section select Source as master (or any other branch you want). You will get site link in the same section, in my screen shot I have removed site link.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This works, but ssl is still something I need to figure.
In my case GoDaddy is where my domains rest (url1.xyz), with nameservers pointing to Cloudflare. Then in Cloudflare the A records points to Github Pages. This is website 1 live, running fine. For website 2 I create a subdirectly in my gh-pages repo with website 2 files e.g. url1.xyz/static/website2/ - Then I create a subdomain in Cloudflare (subdomain.url1.xyz). Then create a page rule (url forward) from the subdomain to the subdirectory containing the 2nd website e.g. subdomain.url1.xyz >> mask forward >> url1.xyz/static/website2/ .. Then in GoDaddy I can configure url2.co.uk to mask forward to subdomain.url1.xyz , which presents website 2 e.g. url1.xyz/static/website2/

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the above. With one github user account(https://< username >.github.io) we can still have multiple static content websites hosted with different custom domains (Eg: domain1.com, domain2.com, domain3.com)We can just create a new repository for each domain and point the A record to github pages IP and CNAME record to < username >.github.io