# How to create more than one github page in one account using another repository

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I already have a GitHub page using as a personal blog. And now I want to create a different Github page, a resume, in another repository using a different theme to my blog so I can't add the resume as a part of my blog.

So, after googling, I knew that I can create several Github page in different repository from the answer of [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563685/can-i-create-more-than-one-repository-for-github-pages)

Then I try to use the method mentioned in the answer based on my understanding.
So I,

1. Directly push the Resume repository to "gh-pages"
   using `git push origin gh-pages`
   And I failed, of course, with the error info below,

   ```
   error: src refspec gh-pages does not match any.
   error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/SeasonLeee/Resume-Chinese                                                                                                                .git'
   ```

which let me know that it might because the Resume repository have no branch so that it failed.

2.Then I go to the blog repository to create a branch named "gh-pages", well, this time I don't know how to push a repository, the Resume, to another repository's branch(the blog page's branch, "gh-pages")

Please, help me! I don't know what's wrong! The question I found seems so easy to operate as they simply said: "push the repository to 'gh-pages'". But where exactly is this "gh-pages"? They said it's a branch, then whose branch? If it's the existing Github page's branch, how to add a whole repository to another branch???

I tried the following command, but none of them worked!

`git push blog-github-page-repository-name gh-pages`

`git push https://github.com/SeasonLeee/SeasonLeee.github.io.git gh-pages`

Help!!!! I really don't what they said "push the repository to gh-pages branch" means...T^T

If you have some much more simple method, strongly welcome you share to me, thank you in advance!

The Resume cost me like 3 days to build and I want to use it instead of using Microsoft word to make one, I really want to use my programming knowledge even though I know I so suck at present. So thank you whoever happens to see this question and share me your solution, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable the github pages from the settings option of the repository. There you can also select the branch from the drop-down. For more details on the github pages feature please read this documentation [here](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/).
Also this [link](https://coderwall.com/p/-bcoua/how-to-create-gh-pages-branch) might be of use as well.

Comment: This is the exact method I got from the Facebook group last night, are you that guy? Anyway, problem solved! Thank you so much!!! XD