# How to create multiple GitHub sites from a same GitHub account?

Tags: git, web, github, github-pages, sitemap

suppose i have created a github page as x.github.io now when i create another repository it published as x.github.io/y
Can I create a y.github.io page from the same account?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563685/can-i-create-more-than-one-repository-for-github-pages

Comment: so we can only have username.github.io page but i i wanna create newpage.github.io but when i create newpage repo its published as username.github.io/new page!!

Comment: You can make multiple github pages. Check this out: https://www.quora.com/Can-I-host-more-than-one-GitHub-page-at-a-time-if-I-have-a-free-GitHub-account