# Custom domain for GitHub repo page

Tags: github

I have set up custom domain for my repo project page on DOMAIN.COM. But how can set it as DOMAIN.COM/REPO instead?

According to the [help page](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/about-custom-domains-and-github-pages), this should be the default.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the response from Github. I don't think this is well-documented on the help page (or I missed it).

To do that, your DOMAIN.COM should be set in your primary repo, i.e. the one name username.github.io. This would be our main repo. Any other repo in our profile for which we've setup GitHub Pages, would start serving at DOMAIN.COM/repoName
You can read more here: [https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#types-of-github-pages-sites]
A discussion from Stackoverflow about this: [[Can I create more than one repository for github pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563685/can-i-create-more-than-one-repository-for-github-pages])