# Other GitHub pages not working after I published my personal site at "username.github.io"

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

Other Github pages were working before, but after I published my portfolio site at "username.github.io", they other sites appears to have turned into a pages of the portfolio site. To clarify: before, I used to host separate websites on "username.github.io/", "username.github.io/", etc. After I put up my main site at "username.github.io", the other websites "username.github.io/", "username.github.io/" etc have turned into pages of the site "username.github.io". "username.github.io" works fine when I visit, but other websites "username.github.io//" appear the same as "username.github.io" but with no data on them.

I read on this [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15564009/6131019) that the `main branch` is where we put up files for "username.github.io". However, I have pushed my files to `gh-pages` following the instructions at [here](https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages). For more context all of the sites are react based.

Comment: Can you include a link to the repo?

Comment: Not 100% certain on how GitHub resolves routing in this case, but the URL structure for user sites vs project sites seems like it would lead to exactly this issue if you have both a user site and at least one project site (since the project sites are separated by URL path on the same host as the user site). My guess is that user sites and project sites are incompatible (or at least prone to error). I'd suggest changing your user site to a project site and using a custom domain name.

Comment: Sorry, as it is my personal portfolio site, I cannot share the repo link for privacy reasons. However, I can share the contents in `package.json` or other files if you think that might be helpful. 

I went through many pages in GitHub pages documentations and made some hours of google searches on this issue. I couldn't find anyone else reporting the same issue I have been having. Thank you very much for the reply.