# Can I efficiently use multiple Github Pages in one repository

Tags: github-pages

Essentially I have a course that I am doing and we have many small projects and websites we make. I am a beginner so please don't use any advanced topics or knowledge. I just need a way to organize my projects. I was thinking about have a new branch for each project but the problem with that is but I have [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROWoo.png) banners pop up. **Another question** is that when I create a new branch does it copy only from the most recent checked out branch? If so how do I change it to copy from main?

What would be the best way to organize my web projects on Github?

Comment: May be this question would help you [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563685/can-i-create-more-than-one-repository-for-github-pages]

Comment: Sorry no I don't think so because I am trying to include it all in one repository.